# proving $ a^{8} - 1 = \left(a^{2} - 1\right)\left(a^{2} + 1\right) \left(a^{2}+\sqrt{\,2\,}a+1\right) \left(a^{2} - \,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,a +1\right) $

Tags: binomial-theorem

- For all real numbers it is true that
  $$
  a^{8} - 1 = \left(a^{2} - 1\right)\left(a^{2} + 1\right)
  \left(a^{2} + \,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,a + 1\right)
  \left(a^{2} - \,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,a +1\right)
  $$
  How do I arrive at this ?.
- I started thinking that $a^{8} -1$ is the $3$rd binomial formula so that $a^{8} - 1 = \left(a^{4} + 1\right)\left(a^{4} - 1\right)$, but then it basically says "stop" in my mental sphere.

I'm preparing for an admissions exam please help !. THX.

Comment: Why stop? You start with a difference of two squares, and after one step of factorization you have a factor that is **again** a difference of two squares. Besides, if you already had the factorization, you could clearly multiply pairs to see which pairs give the product $(a^4+1)$ and which pair gives the other one.

Comment: There are a few posts on this site related to factorization of $x^4+1$, for example, [Factor $x^4+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/698827), [Factorization of $z^4 +1 = (z^2 - \sqrt 2z+1)(z^2 + \sqrt 2 z+1)$ for complex $z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913531) or [Decomposition of polynomials like $1+x^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2918788).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(a^8-1) &= (a^4-1)(a^4+1)
\\
&= (a^2-1)(a^2+1)(a^4+2a^2+1 - 2a^2)
\\
&= (a^2-1)(a^2+1)((a^2+1)^2 - 2a^2)
\\
&= (a^2-1)(a^2+1)((a^2+1) - \sqrt{2}a)((a^2+1) + \sqrt{2}a)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$(a^2)^2+1=(a^2+1)^2-(\sqrt2a)^2=\cdots$$